# Dirichlet Series of Absolute value of Mobius Function equals Ratio of Riemann Zeta

Tags: number-theory, dirichlet-series, mobius-function

I would like to prove this using Euler products:

$$\frac {\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac {\lvert \mu(n) \rvert}{n^s}$$

I have gotten here, but don't know if this is a correct approach.

$$\frac {\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)} = \prod_{p\text{ runs over primes}}^{}(1 + \frac 1{p^s})$$

I appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that $|\mu(n)|$ is multiplicative. Moreover
$$|\mu(n)|=\begin{cases} 1 & \text{if there is no prime $p$ such that }p^2\mid n \\ 0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}.$$
Now just expand the Euler product of $\zeta(s)/\zeta(2s)$:
$$\prod_p \left( 1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right)=\prod_p \left(\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{|\mu(p^k)|}{p^{ks}}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{|\mu(n)|}{n^s}.$$

Comment: Is the middle sum supposed to start at k = 0? Because the sum seems to be off by 1.

Comment: @AmourK Yes, the case $k=0$ supplies 1.